# C program: Writing in a txt file

Tags: c, file

I'm struggling to get this coding problem right. So it's asking me to create 3 text files (**numbers1.txt**, **numbers2.txt**, **output.txt**), where I enter random numbers in **numbers1.txt** and **numbers2.txt** then compare so see whichever one has the smallest number and put it in the **output.txt** file. Below is my code and it still doesn't print the results in my **output.txt**. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I'm on Macbook XCode.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void mergeFiles(FILE *fp, FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp, *fp1, *fp2;
    int noc, count = 0;
    char c;

    char fname[] = "numbers1.txt";
    char fname1[] = "numbers2.txt";
    char fname2[] = "output.txt";

    fp = fopen(fname, "r");
    //check if the file can be opened or not
    if (fp == NULL) //if fail to open file
    {
        printf("Can't open file %s\n", fname);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("successfully open file %s\n", fname);

    noc = fscanf(fp, "%c", &c); //try
    while (noc != EOF) //test
    {
        printf("%c", c); // do
        count++;
        noc = fscanf(fp, "%c", &c); //try
    }

    fp1 = fopen(fname1, "r");

    if (fp1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open file %s\n", fname1);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("successfully open file %s\n", fname1);

    noc = fscanf(fp1, "%c", &c);
    while (noc != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", c);
        count++;
        noc = fscanf(fp1, "%c", &c);
    }

    fp2 = fopen(fname2, "w");
    if (fp2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open file %s\n", fname2);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("successfully open file %s\n", fname2);

    fprintf(fp2, "%c", c);

    mergeFiles(fp, fp1, fp2);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);

    return 0;
}

void mergeFiles(FILE *fp, FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2) {
    int num1, num2, value1, value2;

    num1 = fscanf(fp, "%d", &value1);
    num2 = fscanf(fp1, "%d", &value2);

    while (num1 == 1 && num2 == 1)
    {
        if (fp <= fp1)
        {
            fprintf(fp2, "%d\n", value1);
            num1 = fscanf(fp, "%d", &value1);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(fp2, "%d\n", value2);
            num2 = fscanf(fp1, "%d", &value2);
        }
    }

    while (num1 == 1)
    {
        fprintf(fp2, "%d\n", value1);
        num1 = fscanf(fp, "%d", &value1);
    }

    while (num2 == 1)
    {
        fprintf(fp2, "%d\n", value2);
        num2 = fscanf(fp1, "%d", &value2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you comparing the `fp`s? It makes no sense.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.  In this case, you don't need three files to demonstrate the problem you're having.

Comment: `mergeFiles()` does not merge files. The code does not create the 2 input files. The output as described should be just the smallest number in the 2 files. A single number.  A bit weird. The code seems to (try to) generate a file with the smallest value of each pair of elements on a given position.

Answer (score 1):

In your `main` function, you open the three files and read all the characters contained in the `numbers1.txt` and `numbers2.txt` files, so you place your cursor at the end of the files before calling the `mergeFiles` function.
As you've read all the characters in the files and placed the cursor at the end, your `fscanf` calls to your `mergeFiles` function return -1, so you don't enter any while loops. This why your code didn't write anything in the `output.txt` file.

Why did you introduce the `while` loops in the `main` function?

Tips: use a debugger as `gdb` when you're blocked and build with the flags `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.